# How to add a field widget for multiple file upload?

Tags: 7, files, entities

Is there a module that provides a multiple file upload (Drag and Drop) widget? If there isn't, how can I build one? Will it require a special setup for the server stack (LAMP)?

Comment: You mean select more than one file at a time? In 7 you can create a File field with unlimited number of values.

Comment: No, I mean uploading several files at once.

Comment: Can you describe a scenario?  In Drupal 7's File field, set to unlimited values, you can add any number of files to be uploaded, and when you submit the form they will all get uploaded.  Are you looking for the ability to select more than one at a time?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to drag and drop a hundred photos to an Album node (for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multiupload FileField Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget)

This is what you want. It enables the HTML5 standard for uploading multiple files. Use a normal file field but use this widget. Now one can select several files when browsing for files to upload. This works for never web browser but not IE8.

Comment: How to get file dialog only one time and select all the files at once in webform file field ???

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery File Upload module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_file_upload) is in Dev, but it looks exactly like what you want.

Here's a demo of how jQuery File Upload works: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Will try it out then accept, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use the PLuplaod module in drupal 7. http://drupal.org/project/plupload ..  it support for HTML5, flash and HTML4 also easy to use.